# How to open checked nodes jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have to work on a jstree so that it saves what nodes are checked, but also opens checked nodes and their parents on load. This is the code i have to work with:

```
initializeGeoLevelTree: function () {

        var GeoLevelTree = $('#geoLevelTree');

        GeoLevelTree.jstree({
            "core": {
                "multiple": false,
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                },
                "check_callback": true,
                "data":
                    CreateAdministrator.TreeGeoLevelArray
            },
            "types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-folder icon-warning icon-lg"
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-file icon-warning icon-lg"
                },
                "disabled": {
                    "check_node": false,
                    "uncheck_node": false
                }
            },
            "state": { "key": "createAdministrator" },
            "checkbox": {
                "three_state": false,
                "whole_node": false,
                "tie_selection": false
            },
            "plugins": ["checkbox", "wholerow", "types", "themes", "state"]
        });

        GeoLevelTree.bind("loaded.jstree", function (e, data) {

            GeoLevelTree.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                $("#lblName").text(data.node.original.Name);
                $("#lblType").text(data.node.original.GeoLevelType);
                if (data.node.original.IdGeoLevelType == 4) {
                    $("#officeDetail").show();
                    $("#lblAddress").text("");
                    CreateAdministrator.getOfficelDetail(data.node.id);
                } else {
                    $("#officeDetail").hide();
                }
            });

            CreateAdministrator.SelectGeoLevelAdministratorSavedNode();
        });
        CreateAdministrator.hideLoadingPage();
    },


    SelectGeoLevelAdministratorSavedNode: function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = CreateAdministrator.GeoLevelAdministratorSavedArray.length; i < l; i++) {
            var option = CreateAdministrator.GeoLevelAdministratorSavedArray[i];
            $.jstree.reference("#geoLevelTree").check_node(option.IdGeoLevel);
            jQuery.jstree._reference("#geoLevelTree")._open_to(option.IdGeoLevel);
        }
    },
```

The checked nodes adre stored on an external array, which is processed to find which ones are checked. Is there a way to set those nodes to opened as well? using the open_node or the _open_to methods doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code has jstree.reference for check_node, but then jstree._reference for your open statement. Is it just a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_open_to` seems to do the trick. Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/1267/

Maybe the problem is the format of the IDs you pass to both functions - notice the ID is a string and has no `#` prefix.

Best regards,
Ivan